# JQuery: Current, Well-Formatted, Printable Documentation?

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a current (1.2), well-formatted, printable version of the jQuery documentation.  I've checked the alternative resources page and see the PDF versions from CF and Java, but both are out of date.

The jQuery site has the API browser with "Printable Version" in the toolbox, but it prints terribly, and I don't really want to print one page or tab at a time.

I have a hard time believing that there is no print doc for a tool this popular - all I want is a simple listing with descriptions and examples ON PAPER.

Am I missing something?

I can buy one of the books if I need to, but not sure which is for the current version.

Thanks!

---

**Update:**
I can see that somebody voted this down.  I know it's a pretty basic question, but it is not asked lightly or frivolously.  I have made a pretty solid effort to find this on my own, and am pretty good at finding information when I need it.

Perhaps the person who thought the question not worth asking knows where to find the print doc?

Comment: +1 vote. I don't know why it was voted down. There are a lot of losers on this site. I'm interested in the answer to your question, & I apologize for not having voted it up sooner, but I used up all my votes yesterday.

Comment: Thanks for that =o)

I shouldn't be grouching, it's the free expression that makes this place work - I just thought whoever it was might have some reason (like knowing where the print doc is) for thinking it was a dumb question...

Comment: The problem is that things change so fast that anything printed is probably out of date.

Comment: Why does this have a bounty? What do you want that is not in the answers below?

Comment: Sometimes you just want/need documentation in PDF so you can take it where you need to, even if you're not connected. Hopefully jQuery will one-day have such documentation standard.

Here's a great example of such a project that does so: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

take a look at [this page](http://charupload.wordpress.com/2007/12/07/jquery-documentation-chm/).

it has compiled html help file (CHM) for latest jQuery 1.3.

that guy also compiles another useful CHM manuals.

Comment: CHM isn't exactly print-friendly.

Answer (score 2):

[http://www.amazon.com/jQuery-Action-Bear-Bibeault/dp/1933988355/ref=pd_bbs_sr_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1224036401&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988355)

and

[http://www.amazon.com/jQuery-Reference-Guide-Karl-Swedberg/dp/1847193811/ref=pd_sim_b_3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847193811)

It's not documentation but if the Print functionality in your browser while viewing the tutorials and references on the jQuery site doesn't suffice then these books most certainly will.

Comment: jQuery in Action is a fantastic book.  Just had to throw that in :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also do a little work yourself by usng a service like [PediaPress](http://pediapress.com/) which specializes in converting MediaWiki data to print form.

The jQuery API is all MediaWiki that you could write a simple scraper to gather (just look at the "Edit" pages).

[PediaPress has some code](http://code.pediapress.com/wiki/wiki/mwlib) to parse the MediaWiki written in Python. With that, you can transform the material however you wish.

Answer (score 1):

There are many good jQuery cheat sheets on the Web. Here is one...

http://www.gscottolson.com/jquery/jQuery1.2.cheatsheet.v1.0.pdf

One of these, the Manning book previously referenced, and the excellent online docs make you an expert pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The last time I checked, all of the *printable* jQuery documentation is out of date. There is one for v1.1 available here:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/544-Printing-The-Entire-jQuery-API-As-A-PDF-Using-CFDocument-And-XML-Parsing-.htm

I don't know of any *up-to-date* versions of the documentation though.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use and prefer: http://colorcharge.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/12/jquery12_colorcharge.png

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/ is the best reference I've come across, it also has a [downloadable app](http://api.jquery.com/update/jquery-api-browser-2.0.air) at the bottom that installs as an [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/) application...very handy.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i also disappointed with manning jquery in action book, learning jquery by packt is much better but still not covered most common needs, probably john resig need to write a book himself.

Comment: That would be good.  Honestly, I'd be happy if he'd just write some printable documentation =o)

Comment: He's busy working at Mozilla on the next version of javascript

Answer (score 0):

From 
http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/jquery-benefits-examples-free-ebook.html you can download a chm, and print it. The link is at the end of the entry.

Answer (score 0):

[Here are some jQuery cheat sheets](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/jquery/cheatsheet/) available in multiple printable formats with descriptions and examples on usages.

Answer (score 0):

new ansewr, since this is such an old post, and was the only post i found on this here, http://www.bennadel.com/resources/uploads/jquery_documentation.pdf